# How to create an connection frm WIT2140 cirronet radio to a serial port

Tags: serial-port

I am using WIT2410 cirronet radio to transfer the data wirelessly.
But now i need to interface this radio wiht my PC's serial port.
I need help in how can i make the connection and wat all additional parameters needed for it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect it to the PC. You need to connect at least pins 1,2,3,16 for communication and power. 
Depending on your application, you might need to configure it on the fly so connect CFG to DTR on 
the serial port.
RTS and CTS are good to use for flow control if you send a lot of data or have a slow data handeling power.

I would recommend to connect as many pins as possible of the ones below.

From cirronets W2410 manual:

Pin Signal Type Description

1 Gnd-Signal and chassis ground
2 TxD Input Transmit data
3 RxD Output Receive data
4 CFG Input Configuration selector. Used to switch radio between data and control mode
5 RTS Input Request to send. Used for receive flow control by the host
6 Sleep Input Sleeps/wakes the radio transceiver
7 DCDO utput Data carrier detect. For remotes, indicates successful synchronization
8 CTSO utput Clear to send. Used for receive flow control by the radio
10 Reset Input Resets module
16 Vcc-Positive supply. Min 3.3 v, Nom 5.0 v, Max 10.0

There are a lot of parameters to configure. Once again, depending on your application you need to 
configure it differently. If you are planing to set up a reliable radio network I realy recommend 
using protocol mode 02. If you just want to get it working as fast as possible, try protocol mode 00 which is a transparent mode for point-to-point networks.

You need to set one radio as base and the other(s) as remotes using the 'wb' command.

Be sure to use the same hop pattern. Set the hop pattern with the 'wn' command.

Set protocol mode with 'sp' command.

Switch it back to data mode using the CFG signal pin.

Read the excelent manual here for more information:
http://www.rfm.com/products/data/wit2410dk_manual.pdf

Excelent radio of choice.